# Sum across a range of columns using R

Tags: sum, multiple-columns

I have a table of population estimates by year and gender. The columns are arranged by individual age:

```
Year  Sex     Age_000  Age_001  Age_002  Age_003  Age_004  Age_005  Age_006...Age_105
2013  Male    23       41       45       46       49       49       59        0
2013  Female  26       48       55       56       50       61       60        4
2014  Male    22       40       50       52       49       55       62        1
2014  Female  19       46       59       53       50       43       52        3
.
.
.
```

I would like to request R code that will sum across columns that I specify. For example, Age 0 (alone), Age 1-4, Age 5-9, Age 10-14, Age 15-19, etc. Then collapse age 85 and above. I would also like to group by year and gender, and a third variable (e.g., race)